# Connecting to local SQL Server remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my local machine with a static IP address
`192.168.0.150`

I have enabled **TCP/IP**

[image]

I also did update authentication type

[image]

I however did added exception for 1433 port in firewall

[image]

But when I try to connect from my laptop to this local machine using ip I get this error:

[image]

I did enable the `sa` user and change its password. but no use.

What to do? How will I be able to access the local machine remotely. I have been trying it all day long.

**Note:** I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on local machine.
But I have SQL Server 2012 Management Studio on my laptop, I am not sure if that's the issue why I am not able to connect, but it didn't gave me any message regarding version or something..

Comment: is it sql server or sql server express ?

Comment: @Dhaval its sql server express. with instance name of SQLEXPRESS

Comment: SQL Server **Express** doesn't allow remote connection out of the box - you need to [explicitly enable them!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Problem Solved.

Needed To do two Changes. first added port to connection[image]

But there was something after long searching found out that i needed to change Port In IPALL section

[image]

Answering, that if anyone else might have issue like this might can get help from it. As i had issue related to it.

Many Thanks For Replies.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Management Studio 2012 can connect to SQL Server 2008 too. This won't be a problem at all. It's a constellation I use too.

But have you enabled your instance itself for allowing remote connections?

1. Open up the Management Studio on your Server itself.
2. Connect to your Instance (which should be possible on the Server itself as it isn't a remote connection)
3. Right click on your Instance
4. Select `Properties`
5. Select `Connections`
6. Activate the checkbox `Allow remote connections to this server`

Optionally you can do this using a query:

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'remote access', N'1'
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

Comment: Already enabled.
checkbox is already been checked by me. for "Allow remote connections to this server".??

Answer (score 1):

Open a cmd window and use sqlcmd to connect.  First try sqlcmd without any switches like this:

sqlcmd

That will connect to the locale database using Windows Authentication.  If that fails, add the server switch like this:

sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress

If that fails, add the port number like this:

sqlcmd -S (local)\sqlexpress,1433

You should have success with at least one of these.  Once you are able to connect then go for SQL Authentication.  I see that you are using the sa account to login.  That account could be disabled for security so you'll need to double check it.  Use SQL Management Studio to connect to the database using credentials you successfully applied in the previous steps.  Expand the security folder and look for the sa account.  Right click on it and make sure it's not disabled.  You might want to change (re-enter) the password to make sure that's not the issue either.  After that, back to sqlcmd like this:

sqlcmd -S [whatever worked] -u sa

That will prompt you for the sa password.  Enter it and you should be able to connect.  After that go back to SQL Management Studio and connect using the same credentials.  You've just confirmed both Windows and SQL authentication to the local database.  Now let's handle the ip address issue.  Back to the cmd window.  Enter ipconfig to confirm your ip address.  Now replace the phrase (local) with your ip address and use sqlcmd to connect like this:

sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.50\sqlexpress,1433 -u sa

If you can't connect, then double check the firewall.  I would just temporarily disable it completely just to take it out of the equation.  Then try to connect again using the ip address.  By the way, that IP address looks fishy because the third octet is zero. Normally it's a one. Double check that. Ok if the firewall is disabled and you still can't connect, you have two more things to look at: Obviously tcpip enabled for SQL express.  You'll need to restart SQL express for that change to take effect.  Go ahead and do that, then try to connect again.  Lastly, if you still can't connect, you may have an ipsec policy blocking you.  This is highly unlikely for most end-user machines, so I won't go into detail on this one. Just let me know if you get this far.